# python - Match Everything except the string regex

Tags: python, regex

Data Set

```
Cider
631

Spruce
871

Honda
18813

Nissan
3292

Pine
10621

Walnut
10301
```

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

text = "Cider\n631\n\nSpruce\n871Honda\n18813\n\nNissan\n3292\n\nPine\n10621\n\nWalnut\n10301\n\n"

f1 = re.findall(r"(Cider|Pine)\n(.*)",text)

print(f1)
```

Current Result

```
[('Cider', '631'), ('Pine', '10621')]
```

Question:

How do I change the regex from matching everything except several specified strings? ex (Honda|Nissan)

Desired Result

```
[('Cider', '631'), ('Spruce', '871'), ('Pine', '10621'), ('Walnut', '10301')]
```

Comment: Exclude them: `^(?!Honda|Nissan)[a-zA-Z]+\n\d+` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE31uK/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matching either of the names or only digits, and then match the 2 lines starting with at least a non whitespace char.

```
^(?!(?:Honda|Nissan|\d+)$)(\S.*)\n(.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert not directly to the right

  - `(?:Honda|Nissan|\d+)$` Match any of the alternatives at followed by asserting the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(\S.*)` Capture **group 1**, match a non whitespace char followed by the rest of the line
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(.*)` Capture **group 2**, match any character except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F1jYsr/1)

```
import re

text = ("Cider\n"
            "631\n\n"
            "Spruce\n"
            "871\n\n"
            "Honda\n"
            "18813\n\n"
            "Nissan\n"
            "3292\n\n"
            "Pine\n"
            "10621\n\n"
            "Walnut\n"
            "10301")
f1 = re.findall(r"^(?!(?:Honda|Nissan|\d+)$)(\S.*)\n(.*)", text, re.MULTILINE)

print(f1)
```

Output

```
[('Cider', '631'), ('Spruce', '871'), ('Pine', '10621'), ('Walnut', '10301')]
```

---

If the line should start with an uppercase char A-Z and the next line should consist of only digits:

```
^(?!Honda|Nissan)([A-Z].*)\n(\d+)$
```

This pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!Honda|Nissan)` Negative lookahead, assert not Honda or Nissan directly to the right
- `([A-Z].*)` Capture **group 1**, match an uppercase char A-Z followed by the rest of the line
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNkdLD/1/)

Comment: odd when I run f1 = re.findall(r"^(?!(?:Honda|Nissan|\d+)$)(\S.*)\n(.*)",text) the result I get is only [('Cider', '631')]

Comment: the snippet is what I'm reading from an actual file I just represented that way to make it easer to share.

Comment: @Lacer You have to add `re.MULTILINE`

Comment: that worked! thanks.

Comment: Could you break down the ^(?!(?:Honda|Nissan|\d+)$)(\S.*)\n(.*) so I can learn a little more?

Comment: @Lacer You are welcome. If all strings start with an uppercase char A-Z and the second line should have only digits `^(?!Honda|Nissan)([A-Z].*)\n(\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/CNkdLD/1

Comment: why ?1=why, ?:=why, and why adding \d+ the negation, \S.* = for space

Comment: @Lacer I have added a breakdown of the patterns in the answer.

Comment: thank you for the help and the explanation.  Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

inverse it with  caret ‘^’ symbol.

```
f1 = re.findall(r"(\s?^(Cider|Pine))\n(.*)",text)
```

Keep in mind that caret symbol (in regex) has a special meaning if it is used as a first character match which then would alternatively mean to be “does it start at the beginning of a line”.

Thats why one would insert a “non-usable character” in the beginning.  I chosed an optional single space to use up that first character thereby rendering the meaning of the caret (^) symbol as NOT to mean “the beginning of the line”, but to get the desired inverse operator.